# read data from AWS S3 bucket using JavaScript

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i'm trying to read data from AWS S3 Bucket using JavaScript but getting 
error :

> "Error: Missing credentials in config"

```
AWS.config.update({
  "region": "eu-west-1"
});
var params = { Bucket: <BucketName>, Key: "data.json" };
new AWS.S3().getObject(params, function (err, json_data) {
  if (!err) {
    var json = JSON.parse(new Buffer(json_data.Body).toString("utf8"));
    console.log(json);
  }

  else
    console.log(err);
});
```

even if i tried without `AWS.config.update` i'm getting this error.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK if you wish to access a bucket which is not public then you will need to supply your AWS credentials along with the request. Here's the SDK page for building an AWS.credentials object that you put into your options when making the AWS.S3 object.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html

No example because I am not a JS dev and can't write it out of memory, sorry!